# get number of days between two dates in php

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm attempting to get the number of days between two dates but the results being returned are incorrect.  Here is my attempt;

```
  $t_time = get_the_time( __( 'Y/m/d g:i:s A', 'woocommerce' ), $post ); //date of post
    $start_date = new DateTime(); //current date
    $since_start = $start_date->diff(new DateTime($t_time)); //difference
    echo $since_start->d; //number of days
```

Where did i go wrong?  It works for the first couple of posts but then it restarts when the month changes.

Comment: [**RTM**](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) `$since_start->d` !== `$since_start->days` <- Try this one. Simply reading the manual.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<?php

     $now = time(); // Current time 
     $your_date = strtotime("2013-12-01"); // This will parses an English textual datetime into a Unix timestamp
     $datediff = abs($now - $your_date);// Gives absolute Value 
     echo floor($datediff/(60*60*24)); //Returns the lowest value by rounding down value 

?>
```

Comment: can you add some explanation?

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer Explanation added !

Comment: thanks, now is better for the users ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<?php 

$currentTime = time();

$startTime = strtotime("YYYY/MM/DD");

$diff = $currentTime - $startTime;

echo floor($diff/(60*60*24)); // Number of days between $currentTime and $startTime

?>
```